# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError

Tags: java, exception, classloader

I'm trying to run a program called Orphelia ( http://orphelia.gobics.de/index.jsp ) in a Ubuntu environment, but always returns me the same java error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError
at java.util.zip.Inflater.init(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:100)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInflater(ZipFile.java:284)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:229)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:197)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:383)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.hasClassPathAttribute(JarFile.java:486)
at java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.jarFileHasClassPathAttribute(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:33)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getClassPath(URLClassPath.java:915)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:317)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:184)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:209)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:314)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)Could not find the main class: orphelia. Program will exit.
```

I'm not very familiar with Java, but I've been searching in similar posts and it seems to be related with a Path error.

Could someone tell me the basics ideas to understand this problem and how to fix it?

Any feedback will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this

```
Could not find the main class: orphelia. Program will exit
```

The problem might be  it unable to find `.class` file

First `compile` the program and then `run`